# Most Compatible JQuery Lightbox Plugin, Works in All Current Browsers?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, lightbox

We had a designer redo our site and he tried 4 or 5 different JQuery lightbox plugins, none of which satisfactorily work in all the latest generation of browsers: Webkit, Opera, Firefox, and Internet Explorer.

All the ones he tried (I'm sorry, I don't have their names) had weird issues and odd behavior in either IE9 or Opera 11.5, ranging from rendering issues, to animation and behavioral problems, to z-index messes.

Do you guys have a recommended JQuery lightbox plugin that "just works" for the current generation of browsers, plus doesn't completely break down in IE7 and IE8? Preferably also looks "good" out of the box?

Comment: try lightbox and dont mind ie9 and opera 11 :)

Comment: I think lightbox was one of the ones we tried. I can't just "ignore" IE and Opera!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Colorbox is easy, powerful and tested in the common browsers:

Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Internet Explorer 6, 7, 8, 9, Opera 11.

(I personally use this one all the time)

Otherwise try fancybox:

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Comment: Thanks. I love what I'm seeing from colorbox, and we didn't try that one before. I'll wait a bit for some more suggestions before accepting your answer.