# Certain JavaScript doesn't work in IE9 but there is no JS error

Tags: javascript, lightbox

I'm doing some maintenance work on somebody else's site and there's an IE 9 problem. They're using what appears to be a Lightbox to an image gallery. When you click on a certain image on the page, the Lightbox appears, but in IE 9, the Lightbox doesn't show up at all. There's no error or anything - it just silently fails - so I'm kind of at a loss as to how to troubleshoot.

I'm not the best at these kinds of problems. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Here's a link to what I'm working on: http://www.aquilacommercial.com/wlproperties/view/1300-Guadalupe

Comment: are errors disabled in IE9? what is the lightbox plugin called? is it supported in IE9?

Comment: No, apparently Lightbox, ostensibly yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jaitsu, I confirmed that this occurs. For me, IE9 begins to open Lightbox and then immediately opens the image on it's own page. All with no errors.

I'm still unsure on IE9's issue but this might help with an alternate solution:
[Most Compatible JQuery Lightbox Plugin, Works in All Current Browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245959/most-compatible-jquery-lightbox-plugin-works-in-all-current-browsers)

Finally, have you upgraded to [Lightbox v2.05](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#download). Changelog indicates it didn't work on IE9 till 3/18/11. You might need to upgrade some files.

I confirmed that the Lightbox website is using Prototype v1.7. Your site is using Prototype v1.6.0.2.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll try upgrading and see if that does anything.

Comment: Hmm, that didn't do it. And it looks like it's using Shadowbox, not Lightbox. (I upgraded to the latest Prototype and Shadowbox.)

Comment: @Jason, I just downloaded a local copy of the page you're working on. It still shows prototype 1.6.0.2. Either way, I changed the script locally to pull from [Google APIs v1.7.0.0](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js) and it works in IE9.